# TypeScript method to return a React Node

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I are trying to write a method in TypeScript that returns a `ReactNode`:

```
const getNode = (Tag: string, children: string): React.ReactNode => {
    return <Tag>{children}</Tag>;
};
```

The idea is that I can call it like this:

```
getNode('p', 'Hello World'); // returns <p>Hello World</p>
getNode('h1', 'Title'); // returns <h1>Title</h1>
```

However, the method as written above is giving me a TypeScript error on `<Tag>`:

```
TS2559: Type { children: string; } has no properties in common with 'IntrinsicAttributes'.
```

How do fix this error?

Comment: Why would you not use `React.createElement()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend to avoid JSX in this case and use directly `React.createElement(Tag, {}, children);`